# Can you send a TestFlight beta build to a subset of external testers?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

We are using Apple's TestFlight interface in iTunesConnect for distributing a beta version of our app to external testers. It is possible to put external testers into "Groups" however, we cannot figure out how to send the app only to a subset of users, for example, only users within one Group. Does anyone know how to do this? Or are we required to always send our build out to every external tester?

For example, say we have 100 beta testers in two groups - "Initial Beta" with 10 members, and "Wide Beta" with 100. Can we send an earlier build only to the "Initial Beta" group?

Answer (score 4):

This is accomplished by pressing the "EDIT" button within External Testers under the Testing>External Testing tab and then remove users. It's a little confusing, as you may think you are removing users entirely, but actually the users remain in the "Users and Groups" section. To add users, press the "+" button next to External Testers under the Testing>External Testing tab. See attached image.

[image]

Comment: You did not answer his question- he wasn't asking how to create groups, he was asking how to send different versions out to different groups once they're created.

Comment: @jungledev snibbe didn't say how to create groups, his answer explains how to manage external testers in order to send out different versions to them